# native gem installs fine on 1.9.3 but fails on 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-2.0

A private gem with native extensions I have that had worked fine since ruby 1.8.2 and then 1.9.3 is now failing in a wird mode to install on ruby 2.0.0. Instead of installing the required shared object `.so` file, it copies an executable. There are not changes to the gem sources, going back to ruby 1.9.3 (and it's gemset) works fine.

Here is the relevant 2.0.0-p0 verbose output from `gem install`:

```
linking shared-object mygem/mygem.so
make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 mygem.so /home/remus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mygem-0.1.12/lib/mygem
installing default mygem libraries

Successfully installed mygem-0.1.12
...
1 gem installed
```

And these are the artifacts installed:

```
$ ls -al
total 2252
-rwxr-xr-x 1 remus remus 2289443 May  4 13:08 mygem
-rw-rw-r-- 1 remus remus      62 May  4 13:08 mygem.rb
```

For comparison the 1.9.3-p194 output is:

```
linking shared-object mygem/mygem.so

make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 mygem.so /home/remus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mygem-0.1.12/lib/mygem
installing default mygem libraries
Successfully installed mygem-0.1.12
1 gem installed
```

And the installed artifacts:

```
ls -al 
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 2 remus remus 4096 May  4 13:06 mygem
-rw-rw-r-- 1 remus remus   62 May  4 13:06 mygem.rb
ls -al mygem
total 2760
-rwxr-xr-x 1 remus remus 2810959 May  4 13:06 mygem.so
```

- ruby 2.0.0-p0: rake (10.0.4, 0.9.6), rake-compiler (0.8.3), hoe (3.6.0)
- ruby 1.9.3-p194: rake (10.0.4, 10.0.3, 0.9.2.2), rake-compiler (0.8.1), hoe (3.4.0, 3.0.8)

Comment: Can you please include a copy of your `mygem.gemspec`?

Answer (score 1):

So, without seeing your `mygem.gemspec` file, I can't really say for sure, but I suspect you've got the wrong files listed in there. For example, here's an abridged gemspec based on the one used for NMatrix, which also uses `rake-compiler`:

```
lib = File.expand_path('../lib/', __FILE__)
$:.unshift lib unless $:.include?(lib)

require 'nmatrix/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |gem|
  gem.name = "nmatrix"

  gem.files         = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
  gem.test_files    = `git ls-files -- {test,spec,features}/*`.split("\n")

  # vvv THIS LINE vvv
  gem.executables   = `git ls-files -- bin/*`.split("\n").map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
  # ^^^ THIS LINE ^^^

  gem.extensions = ['ext/nmatrix/extconf.rb']
  gem.require_paths = ["lib"]

  gem.required_ruby_version = '>= 1.9.2'

  gem.add_development_dependency 'rake', '~>0.9'
  gem.add_development_dependency 'bundler'
  gem.add_development_dependency 'rake-compiler', '~>0.8.1'
end
```

tl;dr: You might try looking at your line for `gem.executables` and make sure you have the relevant files included.

Comment: So, how is it going with that #each_with_indices method? Btw. I wasn't able to install NMatrix at home, I'll try it on my other machine.